# How to access API Gateway's pathParameters in step function using Serverless framework?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

How to pass the pathParameter ***user_id*** to the first function in a Step Function?

PS: I'm using API Gateway to invoke the step function.

```
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    hellostepfunc:
      name: HelloStep
      events:
        - http:
            path: users/list/{user_id}
            method: GET
            cors: true
            authorizer: aws_iam
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below, hope it helps.

## serverless.yml

```
events: 
  — http: 
    path: users/list/{user_id}
    method: get 
    cors: true
    request: 
      parameters: 
         paths: 
           user_id: true
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But what needs to be done is pass the ***user_id*** to the first function in the step function. I hope it make sense.